# What does 9P2 mean, and how would one solve it?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

We are studying "Sequences, Series, and Probability" and it likely related to binomial theorem and pascals triangle. I've a test tomorrow morning, and if I can't figure this out soon, I'm likely to fail.

Comment: Hi; I would say 9P2 means 9 x 8 = 72

Comment: Why can questions be downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote your question.

Answer (score 2):

$P(n,k)$ is the number of ways to create an ordered sample of size $k$ from a list of size $n$.  It is easy to show that
$$P(n,k) = {n!\over (n-k)!}.$$
Can you develop  the reason why?

Comment: I'd give a more extensive answer if I could figure out how to format this thing properly, and if I wasn't so starved for time, but in short, I know similar relations, but I've no clue as to why they are that way. However, many thanks for the help!

Comment: @Scott You have counted the combinations, now what is the formula to count the ways to order the $k$ selected items (ie the permutations)?

Answer (score 1):

${^9P_2}$ is the number of permutations of the selections of 2 items from 9 distinct items.  That is, the number of ordered selections of 2 items pulled from 9.

This is related to the count of the combinations of 2 items selected from 9, by multiplying that by the count of the permutations of 2 items.

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}{^9\mathrm P_2} & = {^9\mathrm C_2}\times 2! \\[1ex] & = \frac{9!}{\cancel{2!}\;(9-2)!}\times \cancel{2!} \\[1ex] & = \frac{9!}{7!}\\[1ex] & = 9\times 8\\[1ex] & = 72\end{align}$$